# Overlapping an image over a colored div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I tried creating a layout as shown in the attached image but I'm having trouble with the overlapping the image on the red bar on the right. Please, how do i do this in `css` I'm using bootstrap.

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div style="background-color:#2c2c34;" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <aside class="graybar-text">
        <h1 style="font-size:60px">
          The possibilities <br> with SAMTL are <br> endless
        </h1>
        <p style="font-size:20px">
          our essences comprises of a first class Asset<br> Management services, Trusteeship and Property<br> development.
        </p>
        <img style="padding-top:160px;width:100%; z-index: -1;" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x250">
      </aside>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-top:350px;" class="col-md-2">
      <aside class="redbar">
        <div style="padding-left:110px;" class="btn-group-vertical">
          <ion-icon name="radio-button-off"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon name="radio-button-off"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon name="radio-button-off"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon name="radio-button-off"></ion-icon>
        </div>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify. is it a image slider with navigation to slides as dots on the right hand side? What does the red part signify? Looks like you are developing hybrid mobile app.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to put image into container with `position: relative` and `overflow: visible` that would allow it to overlap.

This is simple example that demonstrates this approach:

```css
.main-content {
  background: #ffcc9a ;
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  width: 110%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container main-content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h1>Some text here</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8 offset-2">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x250">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-2 bg-red"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```